# what is $_category->getImageUrl()?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
$_category->getImageUrl()
```

I want to know why this is used. and where we can use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function to get Magento catalog categories image. You can use this function anywhere in the View file.

Here is the code will work for you any `phtml` file.

```
 $categoryID = 3; //category ID
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryID);
 $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl();
 <img alt="" src="<?php echo $_imgUrl; ?>" class="max-width50 img-fluid mx-auto">
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is for Getting category thumbnail.

Magento provides facilities to get the Image URL from a category by using the catalog/category model.

You can get the category thumbnail image by

```
$_category->getImageUrl()
```

Comment: why do you ask a question that you already know the answer in the first place? Or maybe you are trying to post or share a piece of knowledge.

Comment: Before I don't know the exact answer but when I got an answer, to share the knowledge I posted it.